# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Код ошибки:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
<?php
    include("bd.php");
    @$page = $_GET['page'];
    $result00 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data WHERE secret=0");
    $temp = mysql_fetch_array($result00);
    $posts = $temp[0];
    $total = (($posts - 1) / $num) + 1;
     $total = intval($total);
    $page = intval($page);
    if (empty($page) or $page < 0) $page = 1;
      if ($page > $total) $page = $total;
      // Вычисляем начиная с какого номера
       // следует выводить сообщения
      $start = $page * $num - $num;
     // Выбираем $num сообщений начиная с номера $start
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `secret`=0  ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT $start, $num");
      if (!$result) {
    echo "<p>Запрос на выборку данных из базы не прошел. Напишите об этом администратору. <br> <strong>Код ошибки:</strong></p>";
    exit(mysql_error());
     }
      if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    do {
        echo "
         <tr>
         <td ><strong class='titl'><a class='news' href='fullstory?id=" . $myrow["id"] . "'>" . $myrow["title"] . "</a> / " . $myrow["date"] . "</strong></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
         <td>" . $myrow["description"] . "</td>
       <hr style='border:#999999 dashed 1px;' />
             <br>";

      } while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));
     // Проверяем нужны ли стрелки назад
     if ($page != 1) $pervpage = '<a href=?page=1>Первая</a> | <a href=?page=' . ($page - 1) . '>Предыдущая</a> | ';
     // Проверяем нужны ли стрелки вперед
     if ($page != $total) $nextpage = ' | <a href=?page=' . ($page + 1) . '>Следующая</a> | <a href=?page=' . $total . '>Последняя</a>';
      // Находим две ближайшие станицы с обоих краев, если они есть
    if ($page - 5 > 0) $page5left = ' <a href=?page=' . ($page - 5) . '>' . ($page - 5) . '</a> | ';
    if ($page - 4 > 0) $page4left = ' <a href=?page=' . ($page - 4) . '>' . ($page - 4) . '</a> | ';
    if ($page - 3 > 0) $page3left = ' <a href=?page=' . ($page - 3) . '>' . ($page - 3) . '</a> | ';
    if ($page - 2 > 0) $page2left = ' <a href=?page=' . ($page - 2) . '>' . ($page - 2) . '</a> | ';
    if ($page - 1 > 0) $page1left = '<a href=?page=' . ($page - 1) . '>' . ($page - 1) . '</a> | ';

    if ($page + 5 <= $total) $page5right = ' | <a href=?page=' . ($page + 5) . '>' . ($page + 5) . '</a>';
    if ($page + 4 <= $total) $page4right = ' | <a href=?page=' . ($page + 4) . '>' . ($page + 4) . '</a>';
    if ($page + 3 <= $total) $page3right = ' | <a href=?page=' . ($page + 3) . '>' . ($page + 3) . '</a>';
    if ($page + 2 <= $total) $page2right = ' | <a href=?page=' . ($page + 2) . '>' . ($page + 2) . '</a>';
    if ($page + 1 <= $total) $page1right = ' | <a href=?page=' . ($page + 1) . '>' . ($page + 1) . '</a>';

       // Вывод меню если страниц больше одной
        if ($total > 1) {
        Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
        $content .= "<div class=\"pstrnav\">";
        $content .= $pervpage . $page5left . $page4left . $page3left . $page2left . $page1left . '<b>' . $page . '</b>' . $page1right . $page2right . $page3right . $page4right . $page5right . $nextpage;
        $content .= "</div>";;
    }
      }    else {
     echo "<p>Информация по запросу не может быть извлечена в таблице нет записей.</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Точно, точно... Объявил ему $num = $temp[0];. Все, заработало

Comment: > if ($page - 5 > 0) $page5left...

[Мои эмоции](http://i.imgur.com/Mc3yWEQ.jpg)

@lifting, ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с циклами. Вышеприведенный код можно сократить минимум на треть и привести его в довольно привлекательный вид.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А где `$num` определяется?

> Точно, точно... Объявил ему $num = $temp[0];. Все, заработало

Ну да.